# SQL Local Database Set up?

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there anyway that I can play with SQL db stored in server as my local database?

Let's say I have a database in `db1.company.com` that I am not supposed to write to. But I want to practice on the same data. Then how would you replicate the same data and use it for practice SQL updating so that I can write and update however I want?

Comment: Oracle has a good sample HR database. i thin k  sql dev. comes with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Export the tables from the original database, in `SQL` format. Then import that `SQL` locally to create a replica of the original database.

How to do this is going to vary depending on what kind of admin tool you are using, but if you look around there should be easily accessible import/export options somewhere.